# Adding entered items separated by spaces into a dictionary. Python

Tags: python, loops, input, dictionary, spaces

I need to make a program which asks the user to enter the city followed by the temperature there. The city and temperature are separated by a space. The program stops asking for input and reports the coldest city, when the user enters 'stop'. You can always assume that the user enters a city followed by a single space and then the temperature.

```
Sample Output:

Enter city followed by temperature > Edmonton -2
Enter city followed by temperature > Toronto 3
Enter city followed by temperature > Vancouver -1
Enter city followed by temperature > Ottawa -3
Enter city followed by temperature > stop
{'Toronto': 3, 'Edmonton': -2, 'Vancouver': -1, 'Ottawa': -3}
The coldest city is Ottawa -3
```

The problem I am having is how to get the entered item into the dictionary form. I don't understand how it would work with the space being there in the entered item. I have three other programs that follow this format with the input including spaces and I really cant figure out/find how to work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am in a beginner's computing science course.. yeahh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`string.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
d = {}
for i in range(5):
    user = input('Enter city followed by temperature') 
    # use raw_input(prompt) if using Python 2.x
    data = user.split()
    d[data[0]] = int(data[1])
```

Alternatively, you could append each pair as a tuple to a list, then use the `dict()` function:

```
dataPoints = []
for i in range(5):
    user = input('Enter city followed by temperature')
    data = user.split()
    dataPoints.append((data[0], int(data[1])))
d = dict(dataPoints)
```

Comment: Oh! Geez thank you ~~ i was able to finish my program using `d = {}
for i in range(5):
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature > ")
    if(user!='stop'):
        data = user.split()
        d[data[0]]=int(data[1])
    else:
        break
print(d)
alist=[]
for k,v in d.items():
    alist.append((v,k))
alist.sort()
t=alist[0]

print("The coldest city is:",t[1],t[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the input into the key and the value part using the [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

Answer (score 0):

An example ipython session:

```
In [1]: a = raw_input('City temp: ')
City temp: Edmonton -2

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 'Edmonton -2'

In [3]: d = {}

In [4]: a = a.split()

In [5]: d[a[0]] = a[1]

In [6]: d
Out[6]: {'Edmonton': '-2'}
```

There are obviously more pythonic ways of doing this. You can work them out by reading [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Good luck!